# Why my int array printing random numbers when getting the numbers from a .txt file?

Tags: c, file-io, pthreads, locking, mutex

The problem is when I finish reading the file and close it, and try to print the numbers from the array I get random numbers as you see in the picture below.

[image: Numbers after reading the file]

However, when I print them **after** storing them in the array **during** reading the file, it works just fine!

I used the following code to read the file and store the data:

```c
typedef struct clientsStruct {
    int id;
    char actions[SIZE];
}clients;

char line[] = "";
long balances[SIZE];
int bi; // size of balances
int accountsNumber = 0;
int clientsNumber = 0;

void readFile() {
    // remove trailing whitespaces
    line[strlen(line) - 1] = '\0';

    char splitter[] = " ";
    char *ptr = strtok(line, splitter);

    while(ptr != NULL) {

        // if "balance" word is matched, it means we're getting account details
        if (strcmp(ptr, "balance") == 0) {
            accountsNumber++; // increase the number of accounts
            ptr = strtok(NULL, splitter);

            balances[accountsNumber] = strtol(ptr, NULL, 0);
            bi++;
            printf("**************** balance: %d - accountsNumber: %d****************\n", (int)balances[ii], accountsNumber);
        }

            // count the clients based on the existence of "client" word
        else if (strstr(ptr, "client") != NULL) {
            // printf(ptr + strlen(ptr) - 1);
            clientsNumber++; // increase the number of clients

            ptr = strtok(NULL, splitter);

            // get the series of transitions made by client-n
            while (ptr) {
                clients[jj].id = clientsNumber;

                strncat(clients[jj].actions, ptr, strlen(ptr));

                ptr = strtok(NULL, splitter);
                if (ptr != NULL)
                    strncat(clients[jj].actions, " ", 2);
            }

            jj++;
        }

        ptr = strtok(NULL, splitter);
    }
}
```

The .txt file is from the following format:

```
account1 balance 1000
account2 balance 2000
account3 balance 3000
account4 balance 4000
client1 deposit account2 1000
client2 withdraw account1 300 deposit account4 200
client3 deposit account3 500 withdraw account4 400 withdraw account1 100
client4 withdraw account1 40000 withdraw account2 800
```

**NOTE:** I get the correct output of the balances (after finishing reading the file) when run the program using CMD, while I get it wrong if I used CLION. Also, I use `pthread` along with the code, but I comment the threading out and the result remains the same!

I appreciate any assistance!

Comment: With `char line[] = "";` you define `line` to be an array of ***one single*** element, and that single element is initialized to the string null-terminator. What's worse, when you do `line[strlen(line) - 1] = '\0';` the array contains only the string null-terminator so `strlen(line)` will return zero so you use the index `-1` which is out of bounds.

Comment: Also, don't use global variables, that's a very bad habit. And the function `readFile` is rather badly named as it doesn't read anything at all from any file.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude `line` contains each line from the file and it is not going to be empty, using `line[strlen(line) - 1] = '\0';` I just want to remove the null-terminator from each line, even if I omitted this line of code, the problem remains.  function `readFile` is just getting the data from each line which is stored in `line` which is filled in the `main` where I am reading the file.

Comment: This is one of the reasons it's so important to create a proper [mre] to show us. If we're missing context then we don't know what might be going on.

Comment: Anyway, the only string you can store in the array `line` is the empty string, with only the null-terminator. Anything else will write out of bounds and give you *undefined behavior*.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude `strlen("") - 1` does not form index -1.  That  is index `SIZE_MAX` as it is _unsigned_ math.  In either case,  out of array bounds.

Comment: @HadiAyoub Please explain why `strncat(clients[jj].actions, ptr, strlen(ptr));` and not `strcat(clients[jj].actions, ptr);`.  Same for `strncat(clients[jj].actions, " ", 2);`.

Answer (score 0):

Various issues:

**Too small**

`char line[] = "";` is only a 1 character array.  As a *string*, only suitable for `""`.

Certainly should be larger and the code that populates `line[]` should be size aware.

**Wrong way to remove white-spaces**

`line[strlen(line) - 1] = '\0'` assumes the last character is a white-space.

Below code is a hacker exploit.  Consider if `line[0]` was populated with a *null character* that was read.

```
// remove trailing whitespaces
line[strlen(line) - 1] = '\0';  // bad
```

Alternative to lop off a potential trailing `'\n'`:

```
line[strcspn(line, "\n")] = '\0';
```

**Questionable code**

`strncat(clients[jj].actions, ptr, strlen(ptr));` risks buffer overflow.